# translate only from /app/Resources/views with JmsI18NBundle

Tags: symfony, internationalization

Im trying to generate the translation file .xliff with jms_i18n_routing from templates allocated in /app/Resources/views. If is possible, I would like to take just only one twig named "frontend.html.twig"

Im using the next command, but that only generate translations from a specific bundle, but not translate any template stayed outside the bundle directory for example, the file "app/Resources/views/frontend.html.twig" is not translated:

```
php app/console translation:extract en --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing --bundle="AcmeFooBundle"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that translate texts use JMSTranslationBundle. Use JmsI18NBundle only to translate the routes.

**Generate translation files from a specific directory 'app/':**

```
$ php app/console translation:extract en_US --config=app --output-format=xliff --dir=app
```

**Generate translation files from a specific filename:**

1. Add a config to jms_translation

```yml
# file: app/config/config.yml
jms_translation:
    source_language: "%locale%"
    configs:
        app:
            dirs: [%kernel.root_dir%, %kernel.root_dir%/../src]
            output_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/translations
            ignored_domains: [routes]
            excluded_names: ["*TestCase.php", "*Test.php", "*.php"]
            excluded_dirs: [cache, data, logs]
        custom_exclude_from_app:
            dirs: [%kernel.root_dir%]
            output_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/translations
            ignored_domains: [routes]
            excluded_names: ["*TestCase.php", "*Test.php", "*.php", "backend.html.twig", "email_template.html.twig", "another_template_excluded.html.twig"]
            excluded_dirs: [cache, data, logs]
```

2. Execute the following command:

.

```
$ php app/console translation:extract en_US --config=custom_exclude_from_app --output-format=xliff --dir=app
```

Comment: Can you add an example of route translation ? To understand how I can translate that myself as that bundle is not working with Symfony4